# How to write @Html.DropDownListFor (and so) inside jQuery $('#id').http('')?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, html.dropdownlistfor

I need to inject some UI element inside table getting by AJAX, I has an ID of element and I can write the value like this

```
$('#s-@ViewData.Model.SomeID').html('<input type="submit" id="submitInternalData" value="" class="icon-ok"/>');
```

That works fine

Now I need to write some dropdown element.

```
$('#v-@ViewData.Model.SomeID').html('<b>some text:</b> @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.VMtoAdd, (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.VMServers, "your server");');
```

And got an error because `Html.DropDownListFor` inserts a new line

How can I fix it?

Comment: I really think this is bad design. You should get the data by the Ajax request and populate your UI based on the responded data.

Answer (score 1):

No idea what you are trying to achieve with this and why aren't you directly generating the markup from the server but you may try encoding it:

```
$('#v-@ViewData.Model.SomeID').html('@HttpUtility.JavaScriptStringEncode(Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.VMtoAdd, (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.VMServers, "your server").ToHtmlString())');
```

A better approach would be to have a controller action returning a partial view containing this dropdown and then invoking this controller action using AJAX and simply updating the DOM with the partial result.

Comment: I was asked to show some existing form (with table/grid) on it) inside another page (muliptle times) and I need to add into this grid some control to manage content inside. So - It is not so simple to modify the controller: I will need to transfer a couple new parameters of ID and add complex logic where to render controls or not... br...

Comment: These method doesn't work. I got an error that line is too long :)

Comment: Is this a javascript error you are getting? I think you will need to change your design. This approach seems like a very bad design decision.

Comment: My temporary worked solution is to generate hidden table and simply copy values from one cell to other of the desired table.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution that removes endOflines from it is pair: .Replace("\n", " ").Replace("\r", " "))

```
$('#DestinationID').html('@Html.Raw(Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.VMtoAdd, (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.VMServers, "your server").ToString().Replace("\n", " ").Replace("\r", " "))');
```

Comment: I understand that it is no good, but we fly on unfinished airplanes.